# Search bar for searching

Tags: java, android

I want to create a search bar for my app. The app has many activities linked via buttons for each activity. I want a search bar to search for those buttons in order to open that activity. The search bar should be placed in the title bar. If searched for the text on the button only that button should be shown...plz help...new to android development
[image: activites linked via buttons..]

Answer (score 0):

Use a list view with button effect instead of buttons. You can then filter the array list you are passing to the list view.

Comment: ......I have implemented the listview and edittext...now could you help me in searching the listview items

Comment: The below link would be useful http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: But mine is a custom list....and the above code doesnt work for search....

Comment: Here's my code stackoverflow.com/questions/38726559/how-to-implement-search-functionality-for-custom-listview